# Adding Post Title to Canyon Theme Slider

Tags: wordpress, slider, flexslider

I'm using Wordpress Canyon Theme in my website (http://thomasconti.blog.br/). The slider works fine but it would be really great if it also showed post titles and in larger letters, instead of just a bunch of small text like the default configuration is set to show.

Please, if anyone can help, here is the code for the slider:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
<div id="slide">
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <?php 
        $slide = get_option('cany_slide_cat');
        $count = get_option('cany_slide_count');
        $slide_query = new WP_Query('category_name='.$slide.'&posts_per_page='.$count.'' );
        while ( $slide_query->have_posts() ) : $slide_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID 
    ?>  
    <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="slideimg" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_image_url()?>&amp;h=300&amp;w=650&amp;zc=1" title="" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="flex-caption">
    <?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_slide', ''); ?>
    </div>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried to find this info on the web but only found other bloggers using this theme and asking the same question. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please contact the author of that theme for your support option. Also if others are looking for the same you might be able to get some bugs together and provide a bounty to get this fixed in an uncomplicated manner.

Comment: It seems that they do not offer support for the canyon layout, so I don't really know what to do. If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that plugin but from your question I'd say you need to put a *wordpress template tags* for the title in here:

```
<div class="flex-caption">
    <!-- at this place -->
    <?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_slide', ''); ?>
</div>
```

E.g. mock that with some dummy HTML and headlien:

```
<div class="flex-caption">
    <h2>This is My Headline that is Just There</h2>
    <?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_slide', ''); ?>
</div>
```

Style it via your themes CSS and for the content use [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title):

```
<div class="flex-caption">
    <?php the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' ); ?>
    <?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_slide', ''); ?>
</div>
```

Depending on your styling needs you might want to introduce more markup.

To link the title you use `the_permalink()` again as you already have in your code. That could do it, so hopefully this gives you some pointers.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked perfectly, now I just have to fine tune it. Thank you!!